# LineSearchWarning: The line search algorithm did not converge

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have done hyperparameter tuning using logistic regression and I get the error the line search algorithm did not converge. HOw do I resolve this error?

```
 # grid searching key hyperparametres for logistic regression

# define models and parameters
lr_model = LogisticRegression()
solvers = ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear']
penalty = ['l2']
c_values = [100, 10, 1.0, 0.1, 0.01]
# define grid search
grid = dict(solver=solvers,penalty=penalty,C=c_values)
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=lr_model, param_grid=grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=cv, scoring='accuracy',error_score=0)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(x, y)
# summarize results
print("Accuracy rate of Logistic Regression: %f using %s" % (grid_result.best_score_, grid_result.best_params_))
```

Comment: You don't show any error message.

Answer (score 2):

Increase the maximum iteration (max_iter) to a higher value and/or change the solver. Since you have not taken max_iter as an additional argument, it is taking the default number of iterations.